# How to get minimum records from the Oracle fusion run report API

Tags: oracle, middleware, obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

#### Requirement:

I am using the [runReport](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22259/reportservice.htm#BIPDV389) API from the Oracle fusion report service to get the data by passing the parameter values as arguments. It generally takes more time for larger reports. So is there any way to get the total row count or else minimum records like 10 to 100 rows only for the data preview?

#### Methods tried:

I have tried using the [getReportSampleData](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22259/reportservice.htm#BIPDV359) method but this API won't consider the parameters.

Also tried setting the `sizeOfDataChunkDownload` to 1 MB like that property in the `ReportRequest` class while executing the `runReport(ReportRequest reportRequest, String userID, String password)` API, however, the resultant response isn't a complete XML and it won't be parsed properly.

> So please share the best way to get the correct and minimal records from the `Oracle fusion BI reports(.xdo)`